# How do I get rid of showad.js in windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, virus-removal, malware-removal

I keep getting this pop-up at the bottom of my screen that asks me what I want to do with Showad.js? It gives me the choice of Save - Save as or cancel. I always hit cancel. Is the sites I see with free downloads for getting rid of this pop-up safe? I have Kaspersky Total Security and Malwarebytes they don't even detect them I guess. I'm not real smart when it comes to computers but I don't think this is a good thing to have. And I have had GeekSquad work on my computer 4 times in three weeks and nothing has changed.I could use all the help I can get.

Comment: can you check which extensions are active in your browser? it sounds like you have an adware problem and the most common cause is an unwanted browser extension.

Comment: *" Is the sites I see with free downloads for getting rid of this pop-up safe?"* Sounds a bit like your typical scareware, trying to get you to pay for something unneeded or downloading even more malware. When does that popup appear? Only when you visit specific sites? When you're idle? Just randomly even if no browser is open?

Comment: ItI comes up on Edge while I'm playing Publisher Clearing House

Answer (score 1):

What you’re seeing is a malfunctioning website. Instead of executing the script (and showing ads) it somehow makes your browser initiate a download. What you’re seeing is the regular download workflow of Edge:

[image]

Nothing has “infected” your computer. It’s just that the website isn’t working correctly.